# What do two flats next to each other mean?

Tags: chords, chord-theory

I'm looking at a definition/formula for a chord tone:

Diminished 7th Chord Tone Formula = 1, Flat3, Flat5, FlatFlat7 of the major scale

Do two flats next to each other mean descend by two semi-tones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition is correct; the two flats mean that the 7th of the chord is lowered by two semitones.

A 7th that has been flatted is called a *minor* 7th, while a 7th that has been double-flatted is called a *diminished* 7th. You will often see the  symbol used to indicate double flats, so that a **C<sup>°7</sup>** chord is spelled as C - E♭ - G♭ - B.